# Create link with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to format an link with href like items/?category_id[]=1&category_id[]=2&category_id[]=3
This is for facet search.

```
link_to "Super Categories", params.merge(category_id: [1,2,3])
```

But I cant get the reach the expected result. Square brackets get encoded insted of making an array in GET request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the following in your view

```
link_to "Super Categories", params.merge(category_id: [1,2,3])
```

the `category_id` portion of the querystring will look like

```
?category_id%5B%5D=1&category_id%5B%5D=2&category_id%5B%5D=3
```

There is no issue with these encoded brackets; once Rails receives the `GET` request, `params[:category_id]` will once again be `["1","2","3"]`. You can easily convert this back to integer values with

```
params[:category_id].map(&:to_i) # [1,2,3]
```

Comment: And that if I was a perfectionist? These encoded brackets are so ugly. How ca I prevent them to be encoded? And make ids to join by "&"?

Comment: This **is** the "perfect" way; if you did something to decode the URL string, you'd likely also be allowing characters like `"` or `<` into the URL, which when included in your HTML's source will cause all kinds of problems.